# how to use adb logcat to get time

Tags: android

i want to get time using adb logcat :

i am using below command to get log :

```
 adb shell logcat c:\a.txt
```

but it does not show time , how can i get time in logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-v` option and specify the format you want. You also don't need `shell` in the options (although it also works if you specify `shell`), so you can do:

```
adb logcat -v time
```

See the format options [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat)